# Which table design is better for a Balance that is broken up into multiple parts?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

I have a database where the Balance and Payments need to be broken down into different "money buckets" to show how they are allocated. For example, there is principal, interest, late fees, bounced check fees, Misc, etc. There are up to 10 different money buckets.

Which of these two methods is the better way of designing a database for this, and why?

Option A

```
PAYMENTS 
AccountId
// Other payment-related columns
TotalPaid 
PrincipalPaid
InterestPaid
MiscPaid
BadCheckChargesPaid
...
```

Option B

```
PAYMENTS
AccountId
// Other payment-related columns
TotalPaid

PAYMENT_DETAILS
PaymentId
PaymentTypeId
AmountPaid
```

In most cases only 1-3 of the different balance types are used

Comment: Money buckets?  Sounds more like "T" accounts...  At most, you need two columns: DEBITS and CREDITS, and a type code to indicate interest/etc.  You could get away with one column, and use a negative sign to indicate debits or credits (depending on the ledger account).

Comment: I have some empty buckets here, you could help me to fill them. . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option B is the better normalized, more flexible option (easy to add a new bucket later) and would get my vote.

Comment: +1 because not only is it normalized, but the normalized option allows more than one entry per bucket, with all entries being individually tracked. In a financial app this is almost universally an absolute requirement.

Answer (score 3):

While the normalization fairy can often tempt you in the direction of the latter (as it does me), the former is probably the more sensible. You're only talking about 10 columns (not 500), and there's no normalization rules that are really being broken. Unless there's the strong possibility that this list of payment allocation buckets will grow, I would stay away from the EAV structure just because of the headaches (and innumerable joins in some queries) that it can produce.

Comment: @Rachel: It would tempt me, too; EAV is evil for me, as I *like* the structure even though I know that it's fraught with penalties and potential for abuse.

Comment: I don't think Option B is an EAV approach.  Each record is a well-defined item, a detail of the payment.  There's no question of type safety, and the structure is probably closer to what the user would need for the application (which is separate rows for each detail and a sum at the bottom) than the column-wise approach.

Comment: @Larry: EAV doesn't have to be loosely-typed (even though it frequently is). This follows to a T the EAV structure: Entity (payment), Attribute (payment type), Value (amount).

Comment: It doesn't seem like a lot at first, but when you take into account we need to track Original, Accrued, Paid, and Current Balances, and Payments should track Fees (the % of payment we keep) and remaining balance in addition to the actual payment, it suddenly goes from 10 columns in each table to 40 in the Accounts table and 30 in the Payment table

Comment: @Rachel: If you're talking about 40, then I would move to the secondary table structure.

Comment: @Adam, put so eloquently I have to agree with you.  This form of usage strikes me as qualitatively different in some way from the broader usage, I guess because I see it corresponding _more_ closely the actual nature of the information rather than less closely as in other usages.

Comment: @Larry: Oh, yeah, it's definitely not the same as a typical EAV structure where it's usually just the place where the user can specify custom fields for an entity. Given @Rachel's recent revelation that we're talking about more like 40 columns, it really seems like the secondary table structure is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

Option B seems better to me.  A clincher would be whether your application is designed to show the details like this:

```
 Item             Amount
 --------------   ---------------
 Principal        $10.00
 Interest          $1.11
```

If so, the normalized version is not only "righter" but actually stores the data in a format closer to what your application requires.

To me, the big question is whether you store the payment total in the payment record or derive it from the details.

Comment: In most cases, users only care about the total payment amount. If they are interested in the details, they can click on a payment entry to view the details as to how it is broken out in the form you show here.